# AngularJS: Dynamic Directive, not loading template

Tags: angularjs

Thank you for your attention.

I'm intermediate in my Angular know-how and I'm trying to make a dynamic directive/widget.

I've got massive headache from my neck being out and I'm trying to fix this on my own, but I need someone to point me in the right direction.

I have a directive:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .directive('tool', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'tool-template.html'
      }
    })
  ;
})();
```

tool-template.html:

```
<div class="tool-wrap">
  <svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I'm adding the directive to the view dynamically, using the main controller:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', function(UserModel, Auth, $state, $window, $compile, $scope){
      var ctrl = this;
      var project = $(.project);

      // ...

      ctrl.btnDown = function (event) {
        switch(event.which) {
          case 1:
            project.append(add());
            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
      };

      var add = function () {
        return $compile("<tool></tool>")($scope);
      };

      // ...

    })
  ;
});
```

From what I've gathered I need to use '$compile' to add the new directive element to the dom dynamically. Is this correct?

The issue I'm having is.. I'm able to add the new HTML element tool-tags, but when I open the browser developer toolbar (shift + ctrl + J), the contents of tool-template isn't inside the tool-tags. i.e. The div and svg.

I understand the answer must be painfully obvious but, I'm struggling and I want to get this work done today.

Comment: I've just been reading related questions, do I need to run $scope.apply()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I used:

```
var dir = angular.element(document.createElement("DirectiveName"));
var el = $compile(dir)($scope);
var box = "#NameOfContainer";
angular.element(box).append(dir);
```

1. Create the directive as an element
2. Compile the directive and give it scope
3. Select the element that you want the directive to be added to
4. Append the compiled element to the element you selected

Plunker example : https://plnkr.co/edit/0hWqZzfgWIVPrUhVGIDL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I found that when creating a element using the directive name (if your directive is two words in camelcase), you need to use the hyphenated format. For example: Directive name = directiveName, Element name = directive-name.

I also found that when using templateUrl, it has to be the full file path.
"app/main/tool-template.html"